# Scheme error in substring function

Tags: string, scheme, substring

I am new to Scheme and I am trying to implement a simple function for checking the structure of a string. In particular, I am checking if the string is of the form ss
 This is homework so please dont give full answers.. I just have a bug in my code that I can`t fix.

I get

Error: 1 is not a function [(anon), /, /, (anon), display, s, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, CB, /, CB, /, CB, /, CB, /, CB, /, CB, /, /, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, string-length, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, =, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, -, CB, =, CB, =, CB, -]

Here is my code:

```
  (define CB
     (lambda (s)
        (display "String: ")(display s) 
        (define S_length (string-length s))
        (display " length: ")(display S_length)
            if (not(= S_length 0))

            if (even? S_length)
                (define leftString  (substring s 0 [(- (/ S_length 2) 1)]))
                (define rightString (substring s (- (/ S_length 2) 1) [(- S_length 1 )]))
                (string=? leftString rightString)

                )
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

The parts:

```
[(- (/ S_length 2) 1)]
```

and

```
[(- S_length 1 )]
```

should not have the extra brackets `[]` around them. This results in the error as the expression reduces to `(1)` which attempts to apply `1` to no arguments.